# how to get the word below the cursor when hovering over in LSP?

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, language-server-protocol

I am making a vscode extension for a programming language. At first i was doing all of the work using the extension api. Now i want to switch LSP. The feature I had implemented was that show the definition of builtin functions on hover.

This was the code:

```
vscode.languages.registerHoverProvider("lc", {
        provideHover(document, position) {
            const word = document.getText(
                document.getWordRangeAtPosition(position, /\b\w+(?=\(.*\))/)
            );
            if (builtin_funcs[word] != undefined) {
                return new vscode.Hover(
                    new vscode.MarkdownString(`${builtin_funcs[word]}`)
                );
            } else {
                return null;
            }
        },
    });
```

i was using the `getWordRangeAtPosition` function with the regex `/\b\w+(?=\(.*\))/` to match functions. After getting the function name i searched it in the builtin_funcs array and returned the definition.
[image: function definition when hovering]

Now i want to port this to LSP but i can't find `getWordRangeAtPosition` function equivalent.

Comment: why not `if (builtin_funcs[word] === undefined) { return null; }`

Comment: @rioV8 does that even matter ?

Comment: readability, and get done with cases that you know the result

Comment: Current, no. https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-languageserver-node/issues/616